# Spring webServiceTemplate:The namespace for the prefix 'soapenv' has not been declared

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, soap

I am trying to send a SOAP request with this code:

```
        String strXML = new RegistroUnico().formarXML(unidad, codSIACI, solicitud, "entrada", usuario, pass);

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(strXML));

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(direccion);        

        //Enviamos y recibimos 
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(direccion, source, result);

        StringBuffer sb = ((StringWriter) writer).getBuffer();
        String finalstring = sb.toString();
```

And this is `the formarXML(unidad, codSIACI,    solicitud, "entrada", usuario, pass)` function:

```
private static final String CABECERA_ENTRADA = "<ws:RegistrarEntrada xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.rtaws.aapp.jccm.es\"> \n"
        + " <sUsuario>%s</sUsuario> \n"
        + " <sClave>%s</sClave> \n"
        + " <strXML> \n" + " <![CDATA[\n";
private static final String PIE_ENTRADA = "\n]]> \n" + " </strXML> \n"
        + " </ws:RegistrarEntrada>";

private static final String CABECERA_SALIDA = "<ws:RegistrarSalida xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.rtaws.aapp.jccm.es\"> \n"
        + " <sUsuario>%s</sUsuario> \n"
        + " <sClave>%s</sClave> \n"
        + " <strXML> \n" + " <![CDATA[\n";
private static final String PIE_SALIDA = "\n]]> \n" + " </strXML> \n"
        + " </ws:RegistrarSalida>";

public RegistroUnico() {
}

public String formarXML(String unidad, String codigo, SolicitudRegistro unaSolicitud, String tipoRegistro, String usuario, String pass) throws Exception {
    String xmlString = "";
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        DOMImplementation implementation = builder.getDOMImplementation();

        Document doc = implementation.createDocument(null, "xml", null);

        // Creamos el primer elemento (etiqueta) del XML
        Element Datos = doc.createElement("Datos");
        // Unimos el elemento a la raiz del documento
        doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(Datos);

        // Creamos los 6 primeros nodos
        Element AcuseRecibo = doc.createElement("AcuseRecibo");
        // solo para las salidas
        Element CodRegEnt = doc.createElement("CodRegEnt");
        Element EjercicioRegEnt = doc.createElement("EjercicioRegEnt");
        Element CodUniOrgOrig = doc.createElement("CodUniOrgOrig");
        //
        Element CodSIACI = doc.createElement("CodSIACI");
        Element CodUniOrgDest = doc.createElement("CodUniOrgDest");
        Element Observaciones = doc.createElement("Observaciones");
        Element ExisteRep = doc.createElement("ExisteRep");
        Element Interesado = doc.createElement("Interesado");

        // Creamos los valores que van dentro de los 6 primeros nodos
        Text textAcuseRecibo = doc.createTextNode("N");
        // solo para las salidas
        Text textCodRegEnt = doc.createTextNode("");// doc.createTextNode(unaSolicitud.getNumeroRegistro());

        Text textEjercicioRegEnt=doc.createTextNode("");

        Text textCodUniOrgOrig = doc.createTextNode(unidad);

        Text textCodSIACI = doc.createTextNode(codigo);
        Text textCodUniOrgDest = doc.createTextNode(unidad);

        Text textObservaciones = doc.createTextNode(unaSolicitud.getObservaciones());
        Text textExisteRep = doc.createTextNode("N");

        // a�adimos los 6 primeros nodos
        Datos.appendChild(AcuseRecibo);
        if (tipoRegistro.equals("salida")) {
            Datos.appendChild(CodRegEnt);
            Datos.appendChild(EjercicioRegEnt);
        }
        Datos.appendChild(CodSIACI);
        if (tipoRegistro.equals("salida")) {
            Datos.appendChild(CodUniOrgOrig);
        } else {
            Datos.appendChild(CodUniOrgDest);
        }
        Datos.appendChild(Observaciones);
        Datos.appendChild(ExisteRep);
        Datos.appendChild(Interesado);

        // a�aadimos los valores de los 6 primeros nodos
        AcuseRecibo.appendChild(textAcuseRecibo);
        if (tipoRegistro.equals("salida")) {
            CodRegEnt.appendChild(textCodRegEnt);
            EjercicioRegEnt.appendChild(textEjercicioRegEnt);
        }
        CodSIACI.appendChild(textCodSIACI);
        if (tipoRegistro.equals("salida")) {
            CodUniOrgOrig.appendChild(textCodUniOrgOrig);
        } else {
            CodUniOrgDest.appendChild(textCodUniOrgDest);
        }
        Observaciones.appendChild(textObservaciones);
        ExisteRep.appendChild(textExisteRep);

        // Creamos los elementos que van dentro de interesado
        Element TipoDoc = doc.createElement("Int_TipoDoc");
        Element NifCif = doc.createElement("Int_NifCif");
        Element Nombre = doc.createElement("Int_Nombre");
        Element PrimerAp = doc.createElement("Int_PrimerAp");
        Element SegundoAp = doc.createElement("Int_SegundoAp");

        // valores de las variables
        String tipoDoc = unaSolicitud.getInteresado().getTipoDoc();
        String numIdentificador = "";
        //Issue #11672
        numIdentificador = unaSolicitud.getInteresado().getNifCif();

        String apellido1 = unaSolicitud.getInteresado().getPrimerAp();


        if (apellido1.length() > 30) {
            apellido1 = apellido1.substring(0, 29);
        }
        String apellido2 = unaSolicitud.getInteresado().getSegundoAp();

        if(apellido2!=null){
            if (apellido2.length() > 30) {
                apellido2 = apellido2.substring(0, 29);
            }
        }else{
            apellido2 ="";
        }

        // Creamos los valores que van dentro de interesado
        Text textTipoDoc = doc.createTextNode(tipoDoc);
        Text textNifCif = doc.createTextNode(numIdentificador);
        Text textNombre = doc.createTextNode(unaSolicitud.getInteresado()
                .getNombre());
        Text textPrimerAp = doc.createTextNode(apellido1);
        Text textSegundoAp = doc.createTextNode(apellido2);

        Interesado.appendChild(TipoDoc);
        Interesado.appendChild(NifCif);
        Interesado.appendChild(Nombre);
        Interesado.appendChild(PrimerAp);
        Interesado.appendChild(SegundoAp);

        TipoDoc.appendChild(textTipoDoc);
        NifCif.appendChild(textNifCif);
        Nombre.appendChild(textNombre);
        PrimerAp.appendChild(textPrimerAp);
        SegundoAp.appendChild(textSegundoAp);

        // a�adimos el �ltimo valor
        Element NumDocumentos = doc.createElement("NumDocumentos");
        Text textNumDocumentos = doc.createTextNode("0");
        Datos.appendChild(NumDocumentos);
        NumDocumentos.appendChild(textNumDocumentos);

        // cargamos el xml en una variable de tipo string
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        // Quitamos Etiquetas XML
        xmlString = xmlString.substring(54);
        xmlString = xmlString.replace("<xml>", "");
        xmlString = xmlString.replace("</xml>", "");
        xmlString = xmlString.trim();

        // A�adimos cabeceras-Acci�n
        if (tipoRegistro.equals("salida")) {
            String cabecera = String.format(CABECERA_SALIDA,  usuario, pass);
            xmlString = cabecera + xmlString + PIE_SALIDA;
        }
        else{
            String cabecera = String.format(CABECERA_ENTRADA, usuario, pass);
            xmlString = cabecera + xmlString + PIE_ENTRADA;
        }   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error en el almacenamiento del XML: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }


    return xmlString;
}
```

When the code reaches to `webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(direccion, source, result);` I get this in my log:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><ws:RegistrarEntrada xmlns:ws="http://ws.rtaws.aapp.jccm.es"> 
 <sUsuario>user</sUsuario> 
 <sClave>pass</sClave> 
 <strXML> 

&lt;Datos&gt;
&lt;AcuseRecibo&gt;N&lt;/AcuseRecibo&gt;
&lt;CodSIACI&gt;SJT3&lt;/CodSIACI&gt;
&lt;CodUniOrgDest&gt;850&lt;/CodUniOrgDest&gt;
&lt;Observaciones&gt;Registro de Solicitud Bolsa del SESCAM.&lt;/Observaciones&gt;
&lt;ExisteRep&gt;N&lt;/ExisteRep&gt;
&lt;Interesado&gt;
&lt;Int_TipoDoc&gt;N&lt;/Int_TipoDoc&gt;
&lt;Int_NifCif&gt;111111112&lt;/Int_NifCif&gt;
&lt;Int_Nombre&gt;GONZALO&lt;/Int_Nombre&gt;
&lt;Int_PrimerAp&gt;DE SANTIAGO&lt;/Int_PrimerAp&gt;
&lt;Int_SegundoAp&gt;PEREZ&lt;/Int_SegundoAp&gt;
&lt;/Interesado&gt;
&lt;NumDocumentos&gt;0&lt;/NumDocumentos&gt;
&lt;/Datos&gt;

 </strXML> 
 </ws:RegistrarEntrada></env:Body></env:Envelope>]
 00:34:57,408 DEBUG received:706 - Received response [<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:RegistrarEntradaResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.rtaws.aapp.jccm.es" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><RegistrarEntradaReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?&gt;&lt;RTA-JCCM&gt;&lt;resultado&gt;0&lt;/resultado&gt;&lt;numRegElectronico&gt;20640&lt;/numRegElectronico&gt;&lt;cve&gt;RU0476988435451213036CFRBGRFRCPR&lt;/cve&gt;&lt;fecha&gt;21/12/2018 00:34:56&lt;/fecha&gt;&lt;/RTA-JCCM&gt;</RegistrarEntradaReturn></ns1:RegistrarEntradaResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>] for request [<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><ws:RegistrarEntrada xmlns:ws="http://ws.rtaws.aapp.jccm.es"> 
 <sUsuario>user</sUsuario> 
 <sClave>pass</sClave> 
 <strXML> 

&lt;Datos&gt;
&lt;AcuseRecibo&gt;N&lt;/AcuseRecibo&gt;
&lt;CodSIACI&gt;SJT3&lt;/CodSIACI&gt;
&lt;CodUniOrgDest&gt;850&lt;/CodUniOrgDest&gt;
&lt;Observaciones&gt;Registro de Solicitud Bolsa del SESCAM.&lt;/Observaciones&gt;
&lt;ExisteRep&gt;N&lt;/ExisteRep&gt;
&lt;Interesado&gt;
&lt;Int_TipoDoc&gt;N&lt;/Int_TipoDoc&gt;
&lt;Int_NifCif&gt;111111112&lt;/Int_NifCif&gt;
&lt;Int_Nombre&gt;GONZALO&lt;/Int_Nombre&gt;
&lt;Int_PrimerAp&gt;DE SANTIAGO&lt;/Int_PrimerAp&gt;
&lt;Int_SegundoAp&gt;PEREZ&lt;/Int_SegundoAp&gt;
&lt;/Interesado&gt;
&lt;NumDocumentos&gt;0&lt;/NumDocumentos&gt;
&lt;/Datos&gt;

 </strXML> 
 </ws:RegistrarEntrada></env:Body></env:Envelope>]
```

**ERROR:  The namespace for the prefix 'soapenv' has not been declared.'**

I've tested the request in SoapUI and the result was OK, so I guess the error should be in the Java code, maybe in the Document creation? 
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Why? The prefix shouldn't matter.

Comment: So why am I having that problem?

Comment: What problem? You are trying to change the prefix, why? Why do you need to change it.

Comment: I have changed the prefix 'env' that was generated automatically in the Envelope by the 'soapenv' that appears in my request, as you can see. I've realized that the error may be because of the namespace, but I do not see how to declare the namespace 'soapenv' without getting the error 'The namespace for the prefix' soapenv 'has not been declared.'

Comment: Again the namespace doesn't matter. Why are you even trying to replace it? If it is env and your namespace points to that leave it like that. Don't change it. I simply don't understand the fact that you want or need to change it. That is basically a sign that something else is wrong.

Comment: I have performed tests on SoapUI and effectively the prefix does not influence the response. I just updated my question, with more code so you can see if there is an error.

Comment: Why are you manually creating the request? If you have the WSDL and/or XSD use JAXB to generate the classes and use those to create the request and response. Judging from your logging however there is nothing wrong with either the request nor the response. I suspect some configuration that isn't up to par. However I strongly suggest to use JAXB to (un)Marshall the objects instead of using raw strings.

Comment: I tried to generate the code from the WSDL with maven-jaxb2-plugin, as it is here [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) However the source code is not generated and I get this error: `[ERROR] Could not retrieve the last modification timestamp for the URI [http://registrounicoaplicaciones-desa.jccm.es/registrounicoaplicaciones/services/RegistroTelematicoWS?wsdl] from the HTTP URL connection. The [Last-Modified] header.` The WSDL of the URL looks like this: [my_wsdl](https://pastebin.com/L6gq45xV) Could be an error with the wsdl definition?